# Linear process is non-deterministic

Tags: time-series

We say that $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}\to V$, where $V$ is an inner product space, is deterministic if there exists a finite set $F$ of non-positive integers and complex numbers $\beta_{i}$ such that

$$\|\varphi(1) - \sum_{m\in F}\beta_{m}\varphi(m)\|^{2}=0 \tag{1}$$

The task is to show that for $\varphi$ a linear factor of white-noise $\psi$;
$$\varphi(n) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{k}\psi(n-k)$$
$\varphi$ is not deterministic.

I know that the auto correlation $\gamma$ of $\varphi$ is
$$\gamma(n) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{n+k}\bar{a_{k}}$$

so that the left hand side of $(1)$ is;

\begin{align*}
\|\varphi(1)-\sum_{m\in F}\varphi(m)\|^{2} &= \|\varphi(1)\|^{2} + \|\sum_{m\in F}\beta_{m}\varphi(m)\|^{2} + 2\text{Re}\langle\varphi(1),\sum_{m\in F}\beta_{m}\varphi(m)\rangle\\
&=\gamma(0) + \sum_{m,n\in F}\beta_{m}\bar{\beta_{n}}\gamma(m-n) + 2\text{Re}\sum_{m\in F}\bar{\beta_{m}}\gamma(1-m)\end{align*}

I cannot see anything useful by this, I have substituted in the $\gamma$ definition but I see nothing better. I can show that this term is postive for something easy like $a_{1}=1$ and rest zero but I am hoping to show it in general.

**How can I show that a linear factor (linear process) is not deterministic (the sum of linear factors [linear processes] of earlier times)?**